# AngularJS not working from file:// on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I am on AngularJS v1.3.8 and I am trying to run my AngularJS site from disk on Windows 8.  I have removed all templates in separate files and placed them in script tags in index.

I can run the site locally on all browsers except IE.  No external calls are required, the data and other content are all present on disk.  I have also tried to move all files into a single directory to eliminate the required to traverse sub directories

I am hosting a browser control in my app and cannot run it from a web server.  I have been using unstructured JQuery up until now, but want to move my mini websites to structured / testable code

No matter what I try, I get the following

```
"Error: Access is denied." + "at Anonymous function (file:///C:/Backup/POC/Clients/Client001/angular/appsingle/angular.min.js:86:362)"
```

Thanks
Jaco

Comment: have you tried checking this out? http://stackoverflow.com/a/20848924/1464112

Comment: I am unpacking my site in %appdata%\myfolder\temp\.  This is the location that the app used historically.  All my current mini sites work, only angular implementation on IE not working

Comment: What is your app doing to raise this "Access is denied" message?

Comment: Starting index.htm, nothing special. It does some model binding and event listening. If I open the file in any browser it renders. If I open the file in iis (IE), then it also works. I will replace all min files with debug versions next

Comment: Failing on line 9753 ("xhr.open(method, url, true);"), in method "createHttpBackend", trying to load "views/home.html".  Is there a workaround or configuration that I am missing.  I cannot change the client registry or force IE to run differently.

Comment: I have tried v1.2.8, same result.  Fails on the line 7946 "xhr.open".  It is when my default route (ng-view) must be loaded.

Comment: It seems that its not IE but Chrome too.  I was running a Chrome instance that allowed local file access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that IE and Chrome are blocking any XDR requests to local files ("file:///")

Thus I will not be able to host Angular in the Microsoft Web Browser control, not even in a Chrome frame.

I have created a proof of concept using #Awesomium (http://awesomium.com) libraries and controls.  It seem to be the best solution and provides the implementer with full control over sessions and caching!

I hope this answer will save another from spending the agonizing R&D to get angular working in the Microsoft Web Browser control.