# "SCRIPT5: Access is denied" error when accessing web sites using LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, local-storage, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

One of our client is getting ""SCRIPT5: Access is denied" error when accessing web sites on Windows 8.1/IE11. Only one client is having this issue not all.

when we looked at the error message it turns ut it failed when tried to access

```
_global.localStorage
```

Client said its working fine if they add our site in "Trusted Site".
the problem we having is that none of our dev/test environments has this issue.we are running same version of OS and IE as client. so we are having bit difficulty trying to reproduce this issue.
sa mentioned here 
[Access Denied for localstorage in IE10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102116/access-denied-for-localstorage-in-ie10#) 
i have tried turn on/off DOMStorage/Enhance Protection Mode/Protection Mode but still no  luck. 
our best guess so far is there must be some setting/group policy which applied by Client's IT dept which causes this issue rather code issue as it works for all  other clients.

so my question here is 
**which setting/group policy/domain setting i can check so that i can reproduce this error.**
**How can i fix the issue w/o making any code change** as client has more than 1000 users so only changing the policy by IT dept is the only option here rather asking every user to add to "Trusted Site"

is there anything that i missed to check.

any help would be awesome.

Comment: Did you find out which GPO affects this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and solved it in the next way:

```
let storage;
try {
  storage = localStorage; // throws error if not supported by browser
} catch(e) { // caching this error and assigning fallback
  let innerStorage = {};
  storage = {
    getItem: function(e) {
      return innerStorage[e]
    }, 
    setItem: function(e, i) {
      return innerStorage[e] = i
    }, 
    removeItem: function(e) {
      delete innerStorage[e]
    }
}
```

Best regards,
Aleh