# .click() function give access denied error in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, click, access-denied

document.getElementById(ButtonClickId).click();

above code working fine in the local environment but when I host my application it gives me access denied in IE. for chrome it's working for me

document.getElementById(ButtonClickId).click();

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102116/access-denied-for-localstorage-in-ie10 this may help

Answer (score 0):

It's Browser version issue. In local IE browser was IE- Edge and on Live it was IE 7.  That is the issue code was not working.